# jfreechart & itext for adding many number of barcharts

Tags: javafx, itext, jfreechart

hello can any one help me in adding many number of bar charts to a single pdf. i have a code taken from d website to create a bar chart and save it in pdf. but couldn't save multiple bar charts to a single pdf.

```
import com.itextpdf.awt.DefaultFontMapper;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate; 
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class PieChartDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    writeChartToPDF(generateBarChart(), 500, 400, "F:\\pdf\\bar.pdf");
    //TODO: Add code to generate PDFs with charts
}  



public static JFreeChart generateBarChart() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    dataSet.setValue(791, "Population", "1750 AD");
    dataSet.setValue(978, "Population", "1800 AD");
    dataSet.setValue(1262, "Population", "1850 AD");
    dataSet.setValue(1650, "Population", "1900 AD");
    dataSet.setValue(2519, "Population", "1950 AD");
    dataSet.setValue(6070, "Population", "2000 AD");


    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "World Population growth", "Year", "Population in millions",
            dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);

    return chart;
}
public static void writeChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height, String fileName) {
PdfWriter writer = null;

Document document = new Document();

try {
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
            fileName));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
    Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
            new DefaultFontMapper());
    Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
            height);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);
}

    graphics2d.dispose();
    contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
document.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already doing the right thing except for the loop (I don't understand why you're drawing the same `chart` three times).

Please take a look at the [DirectorCharts](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=262) example on the official iText web site. On the [director_charts.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter14/director_charts.pdf), you can see two different charts each taking half of the space of a page.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
// define a width and a height
// in this case, I took the total width of the page
// and half the height of the page
float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
float height = PageSize.A4.getHeight() / 2;
// Create a Form XObject for a Pie chart
// You already have this part in your own code
PdfTemplate pie = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
Graphics2D g2d1 = new PdfGraphics2D(pie, width, height);
Rectangle2D r2d1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
getPieChart().draw(g2d1, r2d1);
g2d1.dispose();
cb.addTemplate(pie, 0, height);
// Create a Form XObject for a Bar chart
PdfTemplate bar = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
Graphics2D g2d2 = new PdfGraphics2D(bar, width, height);
Rectangle2D r2d2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
getBarChart().draw(g2d2, r2d2);
g2d2.dispose();
cb.addTemplate(bar, 0, 0);
```

The `getPieChart()` and `getBarChart()` method both create a `JFreeChart` object.

As you can see, you always have to create a `PdfTemplate` object (aka Form XObject) with a specific dimension and draw the chart onto that `PdfTemplate`. From that moment on, you can position the `PdfTemplate` on a page. If you want to switch to a new page, do:

```
document.newPage();
```

Also: if you don't want to use absolute coordinates to add the chart, you can wrap a `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image`. Replace the `cb.addTemplate()` methods with:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(pie);
document.add(img);
img = Image.getInstance(bar);
document.add(img);
```

This could be even easier than the code snippet above: you create different `PdfTemplate` object with different charts, wrap them inside an `Image` and add them to the `document`. **Important:** you'll have to use smaller rectangles if you want to wrap the charts inside an `Image`, because otherwise, you won't be able to fit the charts on a single page (due to the default margins).

If you want to add the *same* barchart more than once, it goes without saying that you can either repeat the `addTemplate()` method with the *same* template and different coordinates more than once. If you wrap the template inside an `Image` object, you can add the *same* image to the `document` more than once.

Comment: i just asked for a overview. i m gonna put different charts inside d pdf. thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "i just asked for a overview"? My answer explains how you can put different charts inside a single PDF.

Comment: actually i use desmoj lib and it returns many histograms. i m preparing charts for all the histograms. i want to add all the charts to a single pdf. but your answer helped me a lot. thanks...

Comment: sir, i have some doubts in this coding, can u help me out personally. can u give me your mail ID else u mail me to this. srini26juin@yahoo.com if possible.

Comment: That privilege is only reserved to customers. If you're not a customer and you have a question, you have to post it here. If you want personal advice, you'll receive an invoice.

Comment: ho okay. thanks.. does this chart automatically fits into d pdf..? as a pane in javafx...!!

Comment: Er... I'll assume that you don't know anything about PDF. PDF is a Page Description Format that defines a layout, unlike for instance HTML which is a mark-up language that doesn't tell you anything about layout (although many people mistake HTML for a layouting format). In PDF, you need to define all coordinates. For instance: a page has a fixed size. In my example I use that size to define the dimension of the chart so that it fits into the PDF. In other words: I've already answered your additional question.

Comment: can it be done simply done like this...?    'document.newPage();
            PdfTemplate bar3 = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
            Graphics2D g2d3 = new PdfGraphics2D(bar3,width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
            Rectangle2D r2d3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
            c3.draw(g2d3, r2d3);
            g2d1.dispose();cb.addTemplate(bar3, 0, height);' for adding a chart to the new page..!! here c3 is a method that returns a JFreechart.

Comment: You're kind of sloppy. You use a comment for code (bad formatting). `c3` is an object, not a method. It is unclear where you got the values for `width` and `height`. It is unclear why you add the template at the coordinate `(0, height)`. I understand what you want to achieve. I don't understand what's keeping you from writing the correct code. What exactly is it that you don't understand? The fact that I have so many questions about a single comment of yours may reveal that you should be more accurate in general (when asking questions as well as when writing code).

Comment: actually i have 4 methods which returns charts. i want to add 1st two charts in the 1st page and the next two charts in the 2nd page.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/photos/102893295646199183459/albums/6021410680139177377 this is my output file. in X axis i m not able to view the values clearly. the value is (0,10) (10,20) ........ (90,100)

Comment: Imagine that you print a chart on paper and there isn't enough space to add (0, 10), (10, 20),... Instead (0...), (10...),... is printed. Would you ask somebody if you can somehow zoom into that paper, change its resolution, the way is done in JavaFx? No you wouldn't because you know that's not possible. Well, PDF is digital paper and if something doesn't fit, it doesn't fit. The only solution to make sure that it fits, is to either change the chart or define bigger dimenstions (for instance one chart per page using landscape orientation).

Comment: JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "", "XAxis", "%",
                dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true,false);       in this code chart is an object of JFreeChart....????

Comment: Of course it is. I don't see any iText-related code in that line.

Comment: so if i create (private static ArrayList<JFreeChart> jfreechartList = new ArrayList();) and is it possible to add many objects to the list with a code like this (jfreechartList.add( new ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "", "XAxis", "%",
                dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);) i will b executing this in a for loop..!!!

Comment: That's the second rhetorical question in a row. Rhetorical questions usually don't invite to giving an answer.