# how to place a table in pdf with a itext

Tags: javafx, itext, jfreechart

```
 public static void writeChartToPDF(int width, int height, String fileName) {
 PdfWriter writer = null;

 Document document = new Document();
    try {
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
            fileName));
 document.open();
 JFreeChart c= generateBarChart0();
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        float wid = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
        float heigh = PageSize.A4.getHeight() / 2;
        PdfTemplate bar = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D g2d1 = new PdfGraphics2D(bar,width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
        Rectangle2D r2d1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
        System.out.println("check 5");
        c.draw(g2d1, r2d1);
        g2d1.dispose();
        cb.addTemplate(bar, 0, heigh);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.

        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));

        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);

        document.add(table);

        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
document.close();
 }
```

what am i missing here..?                                                                  i want it to appear as table in the 1st followed by a bar chart. i have a nearly 5 charts and 5 table and i want it to appear in a new page. so each page has a table and a chart.

Comment: Why are you adding the chart at an absolute position and adding the table with `document.add()`? I'd add the chart to the table if I were in your place. By the way: I'm adding this as a comment, not as an answer. I don't understand your question well enough to answer (your code is weird and your question is unclear).

Comment: when i execute this code, i am getting chart in pdf and my table is getting overlapped on the chart. so what i need is, table 1st and then chart. but both i need it on a same page.

Comment: You have to decide, do you want to control the layouting? Or shall iText control it? In your code you control the layouting of the bar chart (`cb.addTemplate(bar, 0, heigh)`) while iText controls the layouting of the table (`document.add(table)`). Thus, layouting happens in an uncoordinated manner resulting in overlapping areas.

Comment: What mkl says is correct: the table and chart overlap because you are betting on two horses: absolute positions and automatic lay-outing.

Comment: so if i don't position it, iText automatically aligns the charts and table..? i.e if i don't use cb.addTemplate(bar, 0 , heigh) will i get wat i expected..?

Comment: i tried, but i couldn't succeed. let iText automatically align my chart and table. but i need both chart & table on a single page. how can i make it..?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Note that I don't think you deserve an answer because you've never accepted one of my previous answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24031789/1622493 That's not very grateful and it kind of makes me reluctant to answer follow-up questions. Let's hope you appreciate the fact that I decided to answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're a developer, which means that you should be able to understand the answers that are given. For instance: when you asked [jfreechart & itext for adding many number of barcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030205/jfreechart-itext-for-adding-many-number-of-barcharts), I answered that you can wrap a `PdfTemplate` inside an image:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(bar);
document.add(img);
```

I'm not really happy that you didn't accept that answer, because it was a really good answer. I'm even less happy that you didn't follow that advice.

In a comment to your current question, I asked you to make a choice: either add the chart and the table at absolute positions, or use iText to do the layout. By wrapping the template inside an `Image`, adding that image with `document.add()` and then adding the table, you could solve your problem.

A solution that may even be more elegant would be to wrap the

```
for (PdfTemplate chart : charts) { 
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(chart), true);
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
    PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
    table.addCell(cell1);
    table.addCell(cell2);
    table.addCell(cell3);
    document.add(table);
    document.newPage();
}
```

In this example `charts` could be a list of `PdfTemplate` instances.

Comment: i m sorry. i am new to java.. but assigned with a job..! so struggling a lot.. fine. will wrap into a img as u suggested.. thanks a lot..